# Regularity of martingales with respect to spatial parameters

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, flows, quadratic-variation

In *Stochastic Flows and Stochastic Differential Equations*, Kunita is proving in Theorem 3.1.2 that a family $M(t,x)$ of continous local martingales depending on a spatial parameter $x$ takes values in a Hölder space as long as the joint quadratic variation of $M(x,t)$ and $M(y,t)$ satisfies some regularity assumptions.

However, I don't understand his proof (regarding this, see [my other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301636/prove-that-a-local-martingale-with-spatial-parameter-is-differentiable)). Actually, I'm not even sure, if I understand his attempt.

I've searched the internet for a couple of weeks, but it seems like there is almost nothing on this topic. The few things I've found are papers and they just cite the statements of Kunita.

> So, if anyone could explain his argument to me or come up with an other reference, I'd be highly thankful.

Thanks in advance to anybody who is trying to help.